# Connect my application (node, express, mongo) with my local database and query it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I build a small application with node.js, express.js, passport.js and mongodb. I'm new to this technology so I'm trying to test it locally before uploading the code on a server and connect it with mongolab. Now my problem is that I'm not able to see or query all my user locally with my mongo shell, so, everytime I add a user, I'm not able to see if I really add it or not. So far my code is the following:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
```

database.js (config/database.js)

```
module.exports = {
  url: 'mongodb://localhost/expressauth',
};
```

user.js (models/user.js)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
  },
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The code is working fine so far, and every time I add a new user I'm able to obtain a user id (something like that 59397add4905d20f0329125c) and a password.

Now I'm trying to see all my users through the mongo shell so I type MONGO in my terminal and then I type SHOW DBS, so I can see all my database.

I can find the database that I create through my database.js (url: 'mongodb://localhost/expressauth') called expressauth, so I switch to it (USE expressauth) and at the very end I try to make a query (something like SELECT * in mysql) with this method that I found in the documentation => db.expressauth.find().

But I don't receive any data. So I'm not able to test my application (which is actually an web app that I found on github: https://github.com/danielgynn/express-authentication/.

Any suggestion why my mongoshell is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in the mongoshell and already called `use expressauth`, then you should be able to do `show collections` to see what collections are in that database.  The `user` or `users` collection should be there depending on your configuration.  Then you can call `db.users.find()` to get all the users in the collection.

Comment: Great! It works! I missed the "show collection" part. I was trying to query the database in general